# Specify alias on join clause using QueryDSL

Tags: java, sql, querydsl

Using QueryDSL I would create a query like the following:

```sql
select * from cats as C join owners as O on ...
```

For readability reasons I would apply the alias "O" in the join clause, but the DSL doesn't seem to support this:

```java
query.from(cats.as("C")).join(owners.as("O")).on(...)
```

The type of `owners.as("O")` isn't compatible with types expected by join clause.

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 10):

Ok, instead of using the autogenerated static instance of a table, you can simply create it with an alias:

```java
Cat cat = new Cat("C");
Owner owner = new Owner("O");
query.from(cats).join(owners).on(...)
```

Comment: Shouldn't variable names be plural per chance?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Alias in Querydsl like

```
QCat cat = new QCat("C");
```

[Querydsl Alias usage](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch03s04.html)